# mixing and matching data types to produce a desired date format of mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp

Let me start with I have a confused Oracle table that has 2 particular columns in it, 1 for issuedate VARCHAR2(10) and one for compdate VARCHAR2(8). The NLS_DATE_FORMAT for the system session is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'. I cannot change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT as there are a significant set of SELECT's that use this format to convert other timestamps into dates.

issuedate is 'MMDDYYYY' COMPDATE is 'MM/DD/YYYY'

here are the portions of the Select in question

```
    co.issuedate issued,
    to_date(substr(ae.cdts, 1,8)) DATE_JOB_OPENED,
    TO_DATE(substr(ae.xdts, 1,8)) DATE_JOB_CLOSED, 
    co.compdate WORKED,
```

The goal is to subtract

```
    issued-WORKED
```

and get the result in number of days.

Guidance is appreciated

Comment: Do not store date values as strings. Do not use `TO_DATE` without specifying the format model in the 2nd argument to the function.

Comment: Taking the difference of two dates and getting a result in mm/dd/yyyy format doesn't really make sense. If you did today - yesterday are you expecting to get 00/01/0000?

Comment: @eaolson - thank you. I edited the original question

Comment: @mto - I cannot really go change what was done 12 years ago without considerable risk to downstream applications, so the date value has to be a string. I will give your solution below a go

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the solution should be to fix your table so that you are storing date values in a `DATE` data type and **NOT** in a `VARCHAR2`.

The second part of the solution should be to go back through all your old code and fix any instances where you use `TO_DATE` or `TO_CHAR` to make sure they always are passed a second argument to explicitly set the format model and to never rely on an implicit format model set by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter.

---

Since you are storing it as a `VARCHAR2`, just use `TO_DATE` and subtract to get the difference:

```sql
SELECT co.issuedate issued,
       TO_DATE(substr(ae.cdts, 1,8), 'YYYYMMDD') DATE_JOB_OPENED,
       TO_DATE(substr(ae.xdts, 1,8), 'YYYYMMDD') DATE_JOB_CLOSED, 
       co.compdate WORKED,
       TO_DATE(co.issuedate, 'MMDDYYYY') - TO_DATE(co.compdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
         AS days_difference
FROM   ...;
```

---

> and get the result in mm/dd/yyyy format.

If you really want the difference in days, months and years then it gets more complicated:

```sql
SELECT issued,
       DATE_JOB_OPENED,
       DATE_JOB_CLOSED,
       worked,
       TO_CHAR(
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (issued_date - comp_date) YEAR TO MONTH),
         'FM00'
       )
       ||'/'||
       TO_CHAR(
         issued_date - ADD_MONTHS(comp_date, FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(issued_date, comp_date))),
         'FM00'
       )
       ||'/'||
       TO_CHAR(
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (issued_date - comp_date) YEAR TO MONTH),
         'FM0000'
       ) AS difference
FROM   (
  SELECT co.issuedate issued,
         TO_DATE(substr(ae.cdts, 1,8), 'YYYYMMDD') DATE_JOB_OPENED,
         TO_DATE(substr(ae.xdts, 1,8), 'YYYYMMDD') DATE_JOB_CLOSED, 
         co.compdate WORKED,
         TO_DATE(co.issuedate, 'MMDDYYYY') AS issued_date,
         TO_DATE(co.compdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS comp_date
  FROM   table_name co
         -- ...
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (issuedate, compdate) AS
SELECT '10292021', '01/01/2021' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs for the `co` related columns:

> | ISSUED | WORKED | DIFFERENCE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10292021 | 01/01/2021 | 10/28/0000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3954199544e84aa4c1d46f43c196028a)*